# Task item start dates are not displayed in azure board queries (list)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-queues, azure-boards

task items start date are not displayed in azure board queries, Start date should pick automatically while the task is changed to new to Active, even Tasks are completed but start date is not displayed, I dont know what is exact issue here.
please find the attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: The transition state defined on the work item type, doesn't have an action to update the 'Start date' field. The answer from @RoyWang-msft should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

A work around for your scenario is using work item rule. Set the below work item rule in Org Settings -> Process -> Your process -> Task work item -> Rules

[image]

Then you could check the query.

[image]

For more information, you could also refer to the doc: [Add a custom rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops#add-a-custom-rule).

Comment: Just watch out for state changes from `Active` back to `New`, you might want to scrub the start date in that transition.

Comment: in my login, I am unable to see the Rules option, We are using Agile process, do we need any admin role or permissions ?

Comment: Can we set rule for restrict to change state of work items and its restrict for group of people not for everyone